# Can we create a function based primary key in Oracle 10?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

There is a requirement in our application to create the unique primary key which depend on the value of another unique column (ERROR_CODE). But our application is in a geo active active environment (have several active databases which are synchronized using another program).

Therefore even-though we have a unique constraint on this ERROR_CODE field, there is a possibility that each database has a row with a different PK for the same ERROR_CODE. During the database synchronization, this is a problem, because there are some child tables which has the PK stored in one DB and other rows contain the PK stored in other DB. Because of the unique constraint of ERROR_CODE, sync process cannot move both rows to each database (which is also not a good thing to do).

So there is a suggestion to use the hash of the ERROR_CODE field as the PK value.

I would like to know whether we can define a function based Primary key in oracle?

If PK field is "ID",

"ID" should be equal to ora_has(ERROR_CODE).

Is it possible to define the primary key like that in oracle?

Comment: I don't quite understand how a hash on error_code helps you avoid duplicates on separate databases - by its very nature, hash(x) on one instance should be equal to hash(x) on another instance.

Comment: That is what I need, a way to have same PK for a error code, therefore second insert synchronization fails. but the error code is in both databases with same PK. So it is still good. so other database tables also have single PK for same error codes. there will be no rows in those tables with different PKs(some PKs non-existing in that DB server) for the same error code.

Comment: What does hashing give you then? Why not just use error code? ... but you said you already have a unique constraint on error code, so I'm still in the dark about what exactly you're trying to achieve. Can you update your question with some example data, with a set of data from two databases?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 10 you cannot do this, but in Oracle 11 you can. You have to create a virtual column, such columns can be used also as primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ora_has(ERROR_CODE)) VIRTUAL);
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT t_test_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX;
```